# Is this an incorrect usage of JS array.find or a VSCode warning to be ignored?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I need to replace a particular object in an array with another object. 
the approach I'm using is to use find on the original array and then overwrite that found value. As I understand this will change the original array. The approach seems to be successfully achieving what I require but I am getting the 'variable never read' warning in VScode.

**Screenshot**

[image: error displayed]

**Code**

```
for (let newQuestionObj of questionWIthNumericCorrectNumericValue) {
    let requiredOriginalQuestion = allPotentialAnswers.find(originalQuestion => {
        return originalQuestion.originalQ === newQuestionObj.originalQ;
    });

    //change question to new value
    requiredOriginalQuestion = newQuestionObj;
}
```

Are there any issue with this approach or should I ignore this warning?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - but the `.find` doesn't do anything since you override `requiredOriginalQuestion` with `newQuestionObj` anyway.

Comment: Consider getting some sleep or taking a coffee break <3 Happy coding

Comment: VS code has picked up the fact that you have assigned a value to `requiredOriginalQuestion`and don't use that value before assigning it a new value. If you add any line of code that uses `requiredOriginalQuestion` (other that assigning a new value to it) that warning will go away. There is nothing wrong with your use of find there.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum This was good advice. Not sure why this so hard for me to grasp ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a value from an array, you are getting a reference to that object. So the result of your `.find` is a variable (called `requiredOriginalQuestion`) that "points" to the object it finds in the array (`allPotentialAnswers`).

When you assign `newQuestionObj` to that variable (`requiredOriginalQuestion`) you are telling the variable called `requiredOriginalQuestion` to stop "pointing" at the value you found in the array and instead "point" at `newQuestionObj`. The object in the array is not changed in any way.

To do what you are trying to do and replace the object in the array, you will need to make a change to the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) itself. You can do this using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
const arr = [{ value: "one" }, { value: "two" }];
const newItem = { value: "Three" };

console.log(arr);

// find the index of the one you want to replace:
const indexToReplace = arr.findIndex(item => item.value === "two");

// Replace the item at that index with the new object
arr[indexToReplace] = newItem;

console.log(arr);
```

So a simple change to your code would look like this:

```
for (let newQuestionObj of questionWIthNumericCorrectNumericValue) {
    let requiredOriginalQuestionIndex = allPotentialAnswers.findIndex(originalQuestion => {
        return originalQuestion.originalQ === newQuestionObj.originalQ;
    });

    //change question to new value
    allPotentialAnswers[requiredOriginalQuestionIndex] = newQuestionObj;
}
```

In terms of the warning you are seeing in VS code. (as I mentioned in my comment) VS code has picked up the fact that you have assigned a value to `requiredOriginalQuestionand` don't use that value before assigning it a new value. If you add any line of code that uses `requiredOriginalQuestion` (other that assigning a new value to it) that warning will go away. There is nothing wrong with your use of find there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Lots of good answers here but this best clears up my confusion for me while providing an alternate solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the issue here is your scope. lets take it step by step:

```
for (let newQuestionObj of questionWIthNumericCorrectNumericValue) {
    // defining the variable
    let requiredOriginalQuestion = allPotentialAnswers.find(originalQuestion => {
        return originalQuestion.originalQ === newQuestionObj.originalQ;
    });
    //useless find.... because you are going to kill the result of the find.

    // reassign the variable to a new thing
    requiredOriginalQuestion = newQuestionObj;
} // < -- here, requiredOriginalQuestion DIES.
```

so basically what is happening a simplier way is something like

```
for (let something from someArray){
    let newvar = doExpensiveCalculation();
    newvar = "--";
    // and we didnt do anything with it, despite of reassigning to "--"
} <-- newvar doesnt exist anymore.
```

or more explicity like:

```
for (let something from someArray){
    // lets keep doing nothing :D
}
```

so basically your warning says

> requiredOriginalQuestion is declared but its value is never read.

this is happening because at the end of each loop, you did nothing to your `let requiredOriginalQuestion`. also you can check that it will dissapear doing something like:

```
for (let newQuestionObj of questionWIthNumericCorrectNumericValue) {
    let requiredOriginalQuestion = allPotentialAnswers.find(originalQuestion => {
        return originalQuestion.originalQ === newQuestionObj.originalQ;
    });
    requiredOriginalQuestion = newQuestionObj;

    const stringified = JSON.stringify(requiredOriginalQuestion);
}
```

but then you will get something like:

> stringified is declared but its value is never read.

**FINALLY**

if you wanted to override the value with the response from the find, this is what you needed:

```
for (let newQuestionObj of questionWIthNumericCorrectNumericValue) {
    let requiredOriginalQuestion = allPotentialAnswers.find(originalQuestion => {
        return originalQuestion.originalQ === newQuestionObj.originalQ;
    });
    newQuestionObj = requiredOriginalQuestion;
}
```

with this you wont have any warning ;)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `.find` is never used since you override `requiredOriginalQuestion` with `newQuestionObj`

Comment: Well that is not true - `.find` does do something. The value that the `.find` returns is just not used.

Comment: My understanding was find gets the object I need from the array. Then I am overwriting this value thereby changing the found object in the original array? If this not correct?

Comment: Never mind, I now realize my silly mistake. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the element "requiredOriginalQuestion" you found in the array "allPotentialAnswers", you have to access that array and replace the value inside.

replace :

```
requiredOriginalQuestion = newQuestionObj;
```

by

```
allPotentialAnswers[allPotentialAnswers.indexOf(requiredOriginalQuestion)] = newQuestionObj
```